# Which unix command using by php to send an email

Tags: php, email, unix, sendmail

Sometimes mail couldn't reach a recipient, but not every time. I suspect what sometimes server dont send an email, so i want check it manually from command prompt (ssh) and i need exactly command which used by php to send email. How can I get it? Any suggestions?

Im using Zend Framework 1.10.2

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->setSubject('subject');
$mail->setBodyHtml('message');
$mail->setFrom('from@from.us');
$mail->addTo('to@to.us');
$mail->send();
```

I checked code twice and dont found any limits on email count.

Comment: Is this code using the default mail functionality on your machine ? or did you setup a mail server yourself ?

Comment: after a small digging to the Zend code im found out what he is using standart mail() function of php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the PHP mail() function they are using [sendmail](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usendmai.htm)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

php's mail function in linux uses sendmail binary, but frameworks usually have different transport options: native mail, SMTP, etc. First, find out what is your case. After you will find out what MTA your code is using, check the logs of it. E.g. in debian postfix logs are located here: /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Thank you for your answer in my case it using mail() function and unix using sendmail via Exim.